# Post a list in a list of items - Can't retrieve items in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I know this question has been asked before, but i have followed the answers from other threads like this still but still couldn't solve my problem.

So what i have is a form with a list that has another list in it and i would like to retrieve all these items in my post action controller so i can update the permissions in my controller. But i am currently unable to retrieve my items in my post action and i don't know why.

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    <ul class="nav well-tabs well-tabs-inverse margin-bottom">
                        @for (int counter = 0; Model.Count > counter; counter++)
                        {
                            <li @if (counter == 0) { @Html.Raw("class='active'")  }><a href="@Html.Raw("#tab" + counter)" data-toggle="tab">@Model[counter].Permissions.RoleName</a></li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Rechten Content -->
                    <div class="tab-content border-none padding-none">

                        @for (int counter = 0; Model.Count > counter; counter++)
                        {
                            <div @Html.Raw(string.Format("id=tab{0}", counter)) class="tab-pane @if (counter == 0)
                                                                                                {
                                                                                                    @Html.Raw("active")
                                                                                                }">
                                <table class="table table-widget table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Recht</th>
                                            <th>Machtiging</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <!-- Get all the updated permissions -->
                                        @for (int counter2 = 0; Model[counter].Permissions.Rights.Count() > counter2; counter2++)
                                        {
                                             <tr>
                                                <td>@Model[counter].Permissions.Rights[counter2].RightName</td>
                                                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=> m[counter].Items[counter2].Selected)
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[counter].Items[counter2].RightId)
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[counter].Items[counter2].RoleName)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        }
                        <input type="submit" value="Gegevens opslaan" css="btn btn-info" />
                    </div>

                }
```

Model:

```
  public class ViewRolePermissionsModel
{
    public Permissions Permissions { get; set; }
    public List<Items> Items;
}

// Sub class
public class Permissions
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public List<RightModel> Rights { get; set; }
}

// Sub class
public class RightModel
{
    public int RightId { get; set; }
    public string RightName { get; set; }
}

// Sub class
public class Items
{
    public int RightId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

This results as this in my view:
[image: End result html]

This is what my controller generates and what i would also like to get in my post action:
[image: Controller generated code]

What my post action retrieves:
[image]

The results of the post are submitted, just the items (that's what i need)

```
[0].Items[0].RightId    1
[0].Items[0].RoleName   Administratoren
[0].Items[0].Selected   false
[0].Items[10].RightId   11
[0].Items[10].RoleName  Administratoren
[0].Items[10].Selected  false
[0].Items[11].RightId   12
[0].Items[11].RoleName  Administratoren
[0].Items[11].Selected  false
[0].Items[1].RightId    2
[0].Items[1].RoleName   Administratoren
[0].Items[1].Selected   false
[0].Items[2].RightId    3
[0].Items[2].RoleName   Administratoren
[0].Items[2].Selected   false
[0].Items[3].RightId    4
[0].Items[3].RoleName   Administratoren
[0].Items[3].Selected   false
[0].Items[4].RightId    5
[0].Items[4].RoleName   Administratoren
[0].Items[4].Selected   false
[0].Items[5].RightId    6
[0].Items[5].RoleName   Administratoren
[0].Items[5].Selected   false
[0].Items[6].RightId    7
[0].Items[6].RoleName   Administratoren
[0].Items[6].Selected   false
[0].Items[7].RightId    8
[0].Items[7].RoleName   Administratoren
[0].Items[7].Selected   false
[0].Items[8].RightId    9
[0].Items[8].RoleName   Administratoren
[0].Items[8].Selected   false
[0].Items[9].RightId    10
[0].Items[9].RoleName   Administratoren
[0].Items[9].Selected   false
[1].Items[0].RightId    1
[1].Items[0].RoleName   Leden
[1].Items[0].Selected   false
[1].Items[10].RightId   11
[1].Items[10].RoleName  Leden
[1].Items[10].Selected  false
[1].Items[11].RightId   12
[1].Items[11].RoleName  Leden
[1].Items[11].Selected  false
[1].Items[1].RightId    2
[1].Items[1].RoleName   Leden
[1].Items[1].Selected   false
[1].Items[2].RightId    3
[1].Items[2].RoleName   Leden
[1].Items[2].Selected   false
[1].Items[3].RightId    4
[1].Items[3].RoleName   Leden
[1].Items[3].Selected   false
[1].Items[4].RightId    5
[1].Items[4].RoleName   Leden
[1].Items[4].Selected   false
[1].Items[5].RightId    6
[1].Items[5].RoleName   Leden
[1].Items[5].Selected   false
[1].Items[6].RightId    7
[1].Items[6].RoleName   Leden
[1].Items[6].Selected   false
[1].Items[7].RightId    8
[1].Items[7].RoleName   Leden
[1].Items[7].Selected   false
[1].Items[8].RightId    9
[1].Items[8].RoleName   Leden
[1].Items[8].Selected   false
[1].Items[9].RightId    10
[1].Items[9].RoleName   Leden
[1].Items[9].Selected   false
[2].Items[0].RightId    1
[2].Items[0].RoleName   Medewerkers
[2].Items[0].Selected   false
[2].Items[10].RightId   11
[2].Items[10].RoleName  Medewerkers
[2].Items[10].Selected  false
[2].Items[11].RightId   12
[2].Items[11].RoleName  Medewerkers
[2].Items[11].Selected  false
[2].Items[1].RightId    2
[2].Items[1].RoleName   Medewerkers
[2].Items[1].Selected   false
[2].Items[2].RightId    3
[2].Items[2].RoleName   Medewerkers
[2].Items[2].Selected   false
[2].Items[3].RightId    4
[2].Items[3].RoleName   Medewerkers
[2].Items[3].Selected   false
[2].Items[4].RightId    5
[2].Items[4].RoleName   Medewerkers
[2].Items[4].Selected   false
[2].Items[5].RightId    6
[2].Items[5].RoleName   Medewerkers
[2].Items[5].Selected   false
[2].Items[6].RightId    7
[2].Items[6].RoleName   Medewerkers
[2].Items[6].Selected   false
[2].Items[7].RightId    8
[2].Items[7].RoleName   Medewerkers
[2].Items[7].Selected   false
[2].Items[8].RightId    9
[2].Items[8].RoleName   Medewerkers
[2].Items[8].Selected   false
[2].Items[9].RightId    10
[2].Items[9].RoleName   Medewerkers
[2].Items[9].Selected   false
```

Comment: What is your actual question? It isn't clear.

Comment: Sorry my bad, the question is: how can i retrieve my list of items in my post action? Because i am currently unable to retrieve my items.

Comment: Can you post more of your DOM? I can only see the first example.  For every object in your model it should be producing a new index.  If not you need build this up manually. For example I can only see [0].Items[0].Selected. The next one should then be [0].Items[1].Selected...etc

Comment: I can confirm that the indexes are correct, it's indeed building up.

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug to see the contents of the POST message?

Comment: @nik0lias The ViewRolePermissionsModel is also a list.

Comment: The fact it's picked up how the model should be, but the objects inside the array are null is a sign you're very close.

Comment: This article may be of use. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Comment: @PeterSmith I just did and it's indeed posting the info of the items i need.

Comment: OK, I have had problems with MVC failing to serialise embedded lists. One solution I was successful with was using `Request.Form`. This returns a 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection' which can then be deserialised as required.

Comment: @PeterSmith Would you mind sharing some code that has this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sample code patched together. First the controller method:

```
public ActionResult ProcessModel()
{
    ViewRolePermissionsModel newResponse = ProcessRoles(Request.Form);
}
```

and then the method to parse this into the model

```
private ViewRolePermissionsModel ProcessRoles(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection requestForm)
{
    ViewRolePermissionsModel viewRolePermissionsModel = new ViewRolePermissionsModel();

    String[] allKeys = requestForm.AllKeys;

    foreach (String localKey in allKeys)
    {
        itemValue = requestForm.GetValues(localKey).FirstOrDefault();
        //  depending on the localKey either use this to add the value to the model or to build a list to be added later
    }
}
```

Comment: Works as a charm, but there realy should be a legitimate way to do this.